# Are there exact expressions for the Floquet states of a periodically-forced, undamped harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, floquet-theory

For [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/138792/floquet-quasienergy-spectrum-continuous-or-discrete) I was looking for the Floquet states of a quantum harmonic oscillator driven by a non-resonant harmonic force, and I had a rather harder time finding it than the simplicity of the question would suggest. I'm sure the result exists, but it's somewhat buried under a mound of papers dealing with damped oscillators (which are of course interesting, including many real, useful applications in open quantum systems, but the undamped oscillator is also important) and many papers exploring formalisms which are not necessarily that crucial to the result. I would therefore like to ask it here so hopefully there's an easier waymarker for future askers of this question.

It seems, moreover, that these states are not as easy to get at. For instance, the paper

> Squeezing in Floquet States and Quasi-energies of Harmonic Oscillator Driven by a Strong Periodic Field. M. Janati-Idrissi et al. [*African Journal Of Mathematical Physics* **10**, 21-30 (2011)](http://www.fsr.ac.ma/GNPHE/ajmpVolume10N1-2011/ajmp1102.pdf).

is quite recent, and it only goes to second order in the driving. This suggests that maybe these states are not actually known in exact form. In addition, it seems ([*Commun. Math. Phys.* **215**, 245 (2000)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002200000296)) that the Floquet quasienergy spectrum is rather different than from the static case (purely absolutely continuous instead of discrete) so there's more at play, with some disagreements in recent literature.

So: **Are there known, exact expressions for the Floquet states of a periodically-forced, undamped harmonic oscillator?** I'm looking for explicit expressions for a complete, orthogonal set of Floquet states, as well as a characterization of the quasienergy spectrum, and an explanation of any significant differences it has with respect to the unperturbed oscillator and the perturbative solutions.

Comment: Stupid little question: Taking limits of damping going to zero on results for a damped oscillator does not yield anything? Or do you not know damped results either?

Comment: First result from google search: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~hmabuchi/Ph125c/fho.pdf Analytical solution for any force coupled to $x$.

Comment: @MengCheng Can you expand on how that paper is relevant specifically for the Floquet states that I'm actually asking about?

Comment: The problem is exactly solved, closed form expression for evolution operator found. What else do you need to construct whatever Floquet states you are interested in?

Comment: @MengCheng If you can implement that, I'm happy to accept your answer. Otherwise, a reference with no mention of Floquet states is hardly a useful answer either now or for future visitors.

Comment: I posted a comment, not an answer anyway. You should be able to extract the Floquet states from the exact solutions given in the reference.

Comment: @MengCheng I will when I have time. In the meantime, an explicit expression for TDSE solutions does *not* guarantee expressions for the Floquet states (in the same way that the Volkov solutions [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.62.8269) require significant handling to transform them to the Floquet states in terms of Airy functions), so while in this case that might be possible, your assumption of an easy path is unfounded.

Comment: Well, I did not say it is easy, I just don't want to deal with the handling myself. But one has enough information to get the Floquet states.

Comment: I can't comment on your post yet, so I will write here. It appears that the quasienergies and Floquet modes are given in this source here: http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Chapter_5.pdf I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @KevinTham Yes, that's what I was looking for. It would be best if you can summarize the methods and the results in a proper answer (which will then be available for whoever comes next). That will also let you participate a bit more fully on this site.