# Can different Floquet replicas be distinguished (within Floquet's theorem)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, floquet-theory

According to Floquet's theorem, two quasi-energies separated by $n\hbar \omega$ represent the same state. According to this, I would think different replicas are indistinguishable experimentally. However, according to the [linked paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1126/science.1239834) in the [answer of this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/138874/24452), they claim they have observed Floquet replicas. Question is: **Are these really Floquet replicas? Or are they simply the photon induced virtual states? Can this experimental observation really be explained within the frame of Floquet's theorem?**

In another point of view, are Floquet quasi-energies gauge-invariant quantities? If they are, and quasi-energies separated by $n\hbar \omega$ represent the same states, when you observe these states, how come you get different energies? Or does it mean $\epsilon\, \mathrm{mod}\, \omega$ is indeed the gauge invariant quantity?

Comment: See also a [newer paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nphys3609) on those lines, and a more popular summary [here](http://phys.org/news/2016-01-pure-quantum-mechanical-mixture-electrons-photons.html).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you for providing these nice references. I'll look into them.

Comment: My intuition about this is that Floquet replicas *are* distinguishable, in the sense that they somehow are representing states on the larger space in which the system is embedded. That is to say, since the Hamiltonian is time-dependent, this means that it is interacting with an external system (e.g., a time-varying E-field), and the external system should be included with the system of interest, and the states *should* be states of the combined system. As an example, a two-level atom weakly coupled to a strong time-varying field can be treated as a two-state system with a time-dependent...

Comment: Hamiltonian, and the $\hbar\omega$ difference between different quasi-energies in the Floquet spectrum represent *different* resonances in that they represent different numbers of photons in the *field* (at high field, $\sqrt{n}\approx\sqrt{n+1}$ if $n$ is the number of photons, so it all works out). This is basically an approximation of the dressed-state picture, where one actually uses a basis $|e, n\rangle$, $|g, n+1\rangle$ for the combined atom-field system. I would write an answer, but I'm not entirely sure that this is right.